# Can locals be injected into a controller set with ng-controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Referring to the example below, is there a way to use myCtrl instead of myCtrl2, passing an argument as a local instead of attached to $scope?

The [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller) service performs exactly the operation needed to wrap an existing controller, but it can't be accessed from the template.

```html
<div ng-app>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    value of y: {{y}}
  </script>

  <div 
    ng-repeat='x in [1,2,3]' 
    ng-controller='myCtrl2'
    ng-include="'/tpl.html'">
  </div>

</div>
```

```js
function myCtrl($scope, x){
  $scope.y = x * 20;
}

function myCtrl2($scope){
  $scope.y = $scope.x * 20;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Zmym/16/

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit what you are trying to achieve? the question is a bit chatty/theoretical..

Comment: Ok, I'll start deleting...

Comment: The description is good, but I couldn't find the "question" part anywhere:)

Comment: One thing's for sure, You cannot inject locals with ng-controller.

Comment: The $controller service does exactly what I want, but not from the template...I was just wondering if there was a trick to pull it off simply.

Comment: I know, I was talking about the template.. Could you post the answer yourself if you find something out? Or the $controller service option in the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't *quite* tell from your question what exatly you're looking for, but you might try creating your own directive (a modified version of [the `ngController` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js)) can specify controller injectables:

```
app.directive('myController', function($controller) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var locals = scope.$eval(attrs.locals);
      angular.extend(locals, {$scope: scope});
      $controller(attrs.myController, locals);
    }
  };
});
```

You would use it something like this:

```
<div my-controller='MainController' locals='{x: "test", y: 42}'></div>
```

Here's a JsFiddle that demonstrates the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/qBZZk/

Comment: Isn't it a bit risky/overkill to pass locals like that - via the DOM? It doesn't seem so clean to me.

Comment: I would personally probably not structure an app like this; I can't think of any problems it solves that could not be better solved in another way.

Comment: I'm new to angular, so I admit I'm most likely wrong. The thought was, why proliferate a bunch of custom directives when all I want is a separate view and controller and a few args.  Upgrade to a custom directive when needed.

Comment: When we use directives, we are passing locals via the view.  It is better than passing on $scope where there is no defined interface. It is a variation on the "resolve" option used by [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) and [$dialogProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog).

Comment: I understand that ng-controller directives creates a new child scope for it's controller. I see in your code that you are passing the scope that should by the parent. What i'm missing? Thanks

Comment: @ejmarino `scope` is a new inherited scope because of `scope: true` in the directive config.